# error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ')'

Tags: c

```
//Program Written By: Andre Chitsaz-zadeh
//Program Written On: 10/7/12
//Program calculates book cost for multiple book orders. 
//Program written using multiple functions.

#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 5

void inputData();
void processingData(int costs[]);
int costs[5];

int main ()
{
    inputData();
    processingData(costs);
}

void inputData()
{
    int i = 0;
    printf( "\nPlease enter five products costs.\n" );
    while(i < 5)
    {
       scanf("%d", &costs[i]);
       i = i + 1;
    }
    printf("stuff");
    for (i = 0, i < 5, i++)
        printf("%d\n", costs[i]);
}

void processingData(int costs[])
{
     int i;
     for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
     {
          int j, min, temp;
          min = i;
          for (j = i+1; j < 5; ++j)
          {
               if (costs[j] < costs[min])
                    min = j;
          }

          temp = costs[i];
          costs[i] = costs[min];
          costs[min] = temp;
     }
}
```

It is lying.... I am not missing any sort of a semi-colon. I have been stuck at this point in the program for a while and it seems like it is something stupid that I am missing. The only time that I get this error is when I am missing semicolons and I have thoroughly checked my program multilple times... Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Compilers don't lie.

In your `inputData` function:

```
for (i = 0, i < 5, i++)
```

Should be:

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

Strangely, you got the for loop right in your `processingData` function.

Comment: @user1724390: Start noticing that compiler errors generally come with line numbers that would help you find where in the code it is it complains about?

Comment: Looks like you are using MSVC++. This compiler doesn't generate friendly error messages really, not for human unless. But as @smassey mentioned, try to use a IDE. A good IDE.

Comment: XD _not for human unless_  I agree with you hahaha. user1724390, Software libre is your best bet, GCC is a very powerful compiler, it's used to compile Linux and various other awesome applications out there.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the for loop in

```
void inputData()

{
    int i = 0;
    printf( "\nPlease enter five products costs.\n" );
    while(i < 5)
    {
    scanf("%d", &costs[i]);
    i = i + 1;

    }
    printf("stuff");
    for (i = 0, i < 5, i++)
        printf("%d\n", costs[i]);

    return;
}
```

with the following for loop

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
for (i = 0, i < 5, i++)
```

It should be

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```